# This library has been renamed to `eth-utils`. The `ethereum-utils` package will no longer recieve updates. Please update your dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, git, setuptools, setup.py, web3py

When I try to link the Python file to the smart contract
i run `python3 "project name ".py` command
i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1_accounts.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web3 import Web3 
  File "/home/esraa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from web3.main import Web3
  File "/home/esraa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from eth_utils import (
  File "/home/esraa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eth_utils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    raise DeprecationWarning(
DeprecationWarning: This library has been renamed to `eth-utils`.  The `ethereum-utils` package will no longer recieve updates.  Please update your dependencies accordingly.
```

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/1698

Comment: thanks to @phd for providing the context. Israa, i don't think stackoverflow is the place for this particular type of error. Opening an issue on the project in question is the correct way to resolve it. It's not a general programming problem, and you don't want to post all of the relevant code on SO.